# I'm confused, where's the string in my Python code when I calculate this field in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to give polygons values in a layer based on the sum population within other adjacent polygons. The polygons are adjacent as I have already sorted them through the appropriate field. This is my code:

```
def CreatePolls(DB_ID, pop):
    for i in DB_ID:
        SumPop = 0
        PollCount = 1        
        SumPop += pop
        if SumPop < 500:
            return PollCount
        elif SumPop > 500:
            return PollCount
            PollCount += 1
            SumPop = 0
arcpy.CalculateField_management('DB_Test', 'Poll_Div', CreatePolls("!DB_ID!","!Population!"))
```

When I try to run it I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in CreatePolls
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `SumPop += "!Population!"`.  You can't actually call `CreatePolls` from within your python code.  You need to write the code block as a string and pass that into `CalculateField`, as seen in the examples: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm

Comment: That worked mikewatt. Thanks! Now I got to figure out why PollCount is not increasing by 1 haha!

Comment: There is no increment because you don't have an increment anywhere in the viable code path (the lines after a `return` at the same indent level will never be executed).

Answer (score 1):

As your `SumPop` variable `=0`, we know with certainty this is an **int**.
Your `pop` variable is whatever your `!Population!` field is. Based on the error, this field appears to be a **str**

You'll need to verify in your data that your Population field is actually a float or double. Alternatively, you can try to *cheat* and cast the field as an **int**. I say cheat because if you have actual string values in here, like "a", this won't work.

`SumPop += int(pop)`

Comment: I tried your method and it didn't work. I even converted the Population field to double just to be sure.